# The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'

Tags: wcf, service, frameworks, entity, dbcontext

I am trying to return an entity object from entity framework 5.0.0  in a WCF service according to [this](http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2010/09/10/MVVM-Tutorial-from-Start-to-Finish) tutorial by Rainer Stropek. I am using EF 5.x DbContext Generator with WCF Support. When I try to debug the service, I get this warning, which prevents it from running:

> The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'.  F:\Dropbox\KelesoftSOMA\KelesoftSOMA.DataService.Administration\Web.config  40  6   KelesoftSOMA.DataService.Administration

The web.config file looks like this:

```
...
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

...

Please help me out.

Than

Comment: can you please post the configSections element of your config.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Here's configSections element:          `<configSections>
     <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>`

Comment: I created the service again afresh and now the tag                  `<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>`                                       is no longer in the file. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me running  vs-2013 preview.

The App.config/Web.config IntelliSense files that get installed by EFTools.msi should be updated to include valid EF6 elements. The xsd for "validating" EF config section in web/app.config file does not recognize newly added EF6 elements. It should be updated so that it does not show squiggles for valid EF6 config file.

Update the config xsd to recognize the elements added in EF6 (i.e. ). These files are located in the Visual Studio install area like ~ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Xml\Schemas". This is not a 100% complete - sorry I am in time-box mode.